# Creating a simple slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I'm trying to create a very simple slideshow, by traversing the DOM. At the moment, I can find the first slide, fade out, and fade in the next. However, it only works **once**.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/fEEu6/3/

```
$('.img').first().siblings('.img').hide();
$('.next').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.slides').children('.img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();

});

<div class="container">
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="img">1</div>
        <div class="img">2</div>
        <div class="img">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">&rarr;</div>
</div>
```

Would anyone know why it only works on one slide, and not until all 3? I'm using this as a learning exercise so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move through by which .img is visible.

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.container').find('.slides > .img:visible').hide().next().fadeIn();
});
```

If you want to go back, just us .prev() instead of .next()

Comment: What will happen after last slide ? It will go blank! This is part of boundary condition which should be always checked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it doesn't work because you are using ":First-child"

```
$(this).siblings('.slides').children('.img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
```

With this code, it will always, fadeout the first child and fadein the next. However, after the first move, the 1st child is already hidden and 2nd child is already displayed, you wont see any difference.

May be u can try adding a dummy class

jQuery

```
if( $(this).siblings('.slides').children('.img.dummyClass').next().length  )
    $(this).siblings('.slides').children('.img.dummyClass').fadeOut().removeClass('dummyClass').next().fadeIn().addClass('dummyClass');
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="slides">
    <div class="img dummyClass">1</div>
    <div class="img">2</div>
    <div class="img">3</div>
    <div class="img">4</div>
</div>
<div class="next">&rarr;</div>
```

NOTE: This will not slide past the last slide (because of the IF condition). But as that is not part of your question, I have ignored going back to slide 1.

**Added**

http://jsfiddle.net/9GZJm/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can add and removed a active class for the img like this:

```
$('.img').first().addClass('active').siblings('.img').hide();
$('.next').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.slides').children('.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').fadeIn();

});
```